# UmbracoCms installation error

Tags: nuget, umbraco

I'm getting this error when I try to run the following line:

```
Install-Package UmbracoCms
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Install-Package : An error occurred while downloading package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2 : ' from source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/'
```

I have tried to do the following:

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.2`

And I still got this error:

```
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2 : ' does not exist in project 'Umbraco_MVC'
```

I also tried to delete the line with Newtonsoft in packages.config, but there is no line with that reference there

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, and you're having an issue with getting JSON.NET installed through NuGet through both methods, then this (loosely related) GitHub issue thread might be of use to you.

https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1041

It involves changing the NuGet API URL you use to a newer version.

If your installation IS working, but you're still getting an issue, check your website bin folder to see if the dll is there. If not, check the References section of your web project to see if the dll is being referenced by your project.

Comment: Hi
Where do I find this website bin folder?

Comment: Your error states that you have a "Umbraco_MVC" project, so if you go to the folder on the file system called "Umbraco_MVC" you should see a folder called bin. Open that and look for a file along the lines of Newtonsoft.Json.dll